# Unity Panel Not Fitting screen correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I am making a little game in Unity3D and I came across a little problem, when I made a Panel inside a canvas, it shows perfectly when in Unity, but in the game, the text doesn't even show or anything.
Here is some pictures:

How it's supposed to look:
https://gyazo.com/50c4b0c5a00d93ba0ce2482884aa4f52

How it looks:
https://gyazo.com/4cc73ff92e479a19717b1937da244484

---

When I took the how it looks pic I couldnt get the whole screen cause it goes away too fast but, it just shows that text.

Comment: How is your panel configuration? Can you post a SS of the `RectTransform`?

Comment: Here it is. https://gyazo.com/71dd1816d6d92b0d33b1e8a0c0797660

Comment: This one looks alright. What about the panel's one? Inside the canvas

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c3988baa1899f83b1acab3063b249342

Answer (score 1):

when working with a canvas in unity, you should make sure your game window is set to a standard resolution, not free aspect.
  Set your canvas scaler component to "Scale with Screen Size" so its the same across different screen, also set you X and Y to be the same ratio( so 16:9 for me as a higher res would be 1200:675 (multiplied by 75)).

See attached photo, hope it helps.

[image]